# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'

Tags: django, psycopg2, sentry

When I tried to install Django packages, I got the following error -

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
{'exc_info': (<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'"), <traceback object at 0x000001E0A17CF1C0>), 'attachments': []}

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\PycharmProjects\virtualenvs\energy-api\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\threading.py", line 72, in run
reraise(*_capture_exception())
File "D:\PycharmProjects\virtualenvs\energy-api\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk_compat.py", line 60, in reraise
raise value
File "D:\PycharmProjects\virtualenvs\energy-api\lib\site-packages\sentry_sdk\integrations\threading.py", line 70, in run
return old_run_func(self, *a, **kw)

.....

.....

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'